# Adding image src in the inline html under javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I am showing a infoWindow on click of the marker on google map , the content of the infoWindow  is an inline html along with img tag the src of the image changes for every marker,I want to get the img src dynamicaly  the code what iv done is

```
var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
  '<div id="siteNotice">'+
  '<img id="image" alt="No Photograph to Display" src="" width="400px" height="250px" />'+

  '</div>'+
  '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">'+title+'</h1>'+
  '<div id="bodyContent">'+
  '<p>'+probdesc+'</p><br>'+
  '<p><b>Open Date:</b>'+opendate+'</p><br>'+
   '<p><b>Status:</b>'+status+'</p><br>'+
  '</div>'+
  '</div>';
```

the image tag must get the src value  must be replaced by url value which contains the dynamic path of the image

```
var url = '<%=imageURL %>'+ "&<portlet:namespace/>imagepath=" + imagepath;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery for it, after print the HTML code on your page:

```
$("#image").attr("src", url); //"url" is your var.
```

Only Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("image").setAttribute("src", url);
document.getElementById("image").src = url; //it works too - http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_html.asp
```

Just for make it simple, after Paul S' comment. If you don't print the HTML on your page, the "attr" code wouldn't work. For print the HTML code on your page, you can use:

```
$("#anchor_element").html(contentString);
// and then
$("#image") .....
```

Using pure Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("anchor").innerHTML = contentString;
// and then
document.getElementById("image")......
```

Comment: Just pointing out that _#image_ must exist as a _Node_ before this will work.

Comment: Good point, Paul S. I said it wit "after print the HTML code on your page", and I had in mind that the HTML code is being printed in somewhere. Edited answer.